# Arduino Pick a random word from array every time sketch is ran

Tags: arrays, random, arduino, arduino-c++

I have some code:

```
char *fruits[]={"Lettuce", "Tomato", "Pineapple", "Apple"}; //This is the array
long fruit1; 
void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600);
 randomSeed(500);
 fruit1 = random(sizeof(fruits)/sizeof(char*));
 Serial.println(fruits[fruit1]);//Prints random in serial
}
```

This code picks a random fruit the first time an arduino sketch is ran, but every other time I run it, it uses the same random fruit it picked the first time the sketch is ran. I want it to pick a random fruit from the array every time the sketch is ran, meaning everytime I turn it on and off I want to see a different and random fruit from the last. Sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

Code source: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=45653.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given seed value you will always get the same sequence of random numbers. You need a different seed every time setup is called:

[randomSeed()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/randomseed/)

> `randomSeed()` initializes the pseudo-random number generator, causing
> it to start at an arbitrary point in its random sequence. This
> sequence, while very long, and random, is always the same.
>
> If it is important for a sequence of values generated by random() to
> differ, on subsequent executions of a sketch, use `randomSeed()` to
> initialize the random number generator with a fairly random input,
> such as `analogRead()` on an unconnected pin.
>
> Conversely, it can occasionally be useful to use pseudo-random
> sequences that repeat exactly. This can be accomplished by calling
> randomSeed() with a fixed number, before starting the random sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly aware of how PRNG functions work at a lower level, but I do believe that keeping the `seed` same might be what is causing the issue.

The [arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/) helps you solve this issue by advising you to implement your code for random number generation the following way -

```c
long randNumber;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // if analog input pin 0 is unconnected, random analog
  // noise will cause the call to randomSeed() to generate
  // different seed numbers each time the sketch runs.
  // randomSeed() will then shuffle the random function.
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
}

void loop() {
  // print a random number from 0 to 299
  randNumber = random(300);
  Serial.println(randNumber);

  // print a random number from 10 to 19
  randNumber = random(10, 20);
  Serial.println(randNumber);

  delay(50);
}
```